# Specifying optional parameters out of order

Tags: macros, common-lisp, optional-parameters

The code below implements a macro call with an implicit optional parameter--implicit because it is buried in the &rest parameter. Is there a better way to code the macro (and its supporting function)--perhaps by making the optional parameter explicit with an &optional keyword (or maybe some other way)? It is preferred that the first parameter is required, the second optional, and the numerous remaining parameters required. Also prefer to keep the macro definition simple, with the work done by the supporting function, if possible (but looking to learn more advanced approaches too):

```
(defstruct action
  name duration slot1 slot2 slot3)

(defmacro define-action (name &rest rest)
  `(install-action ',name ',rest))

(defun install-action (name &rest rest)
  (let* ((slots (first rest))
         (duration (if (numberp (first slots))
                       (prog1 (first slots)
                              (setf slots (cdr slots)))                              
                     0))
         (action (make-action :name name :duration duration
                   :slot1 (first slots) :slot2 (second slots)
                   :slot3 (third slots))))
    (print action)))

(define-action move a b c)  ;first example no duration

(define-action move 1 a b c)  ;second example with duration=1

#S(ACTION :NAME MOVE :DURATION 0 :SLOT1 A :SLOT2 B :SLOT3 C) 
#S(ACTION :NAME MOVE :DURATION 1 :SLOT1 A :SLOT2 B :SLOT3 C)
```

Additional point of clarification: The slot values above are really various specifications represented as (sometimes deeply nested) lisp trees. The function install-action interprets the specs and installs their semantic content into a database.

Comment: If the rest parameters are required, it would be better to just make them regular named parameters. That way users of the macro can see from the lambda-list what they are supposed to give it, rather than having to guess (/read the docs). The optional duration could be a keyword/optional parameter at the end. Or you could have something like `(name (&optional (duration 0)) slot1 slot2 slot3)` for the macro.

Comment: I'd prefer to use your solution if I can get it to work. (Didn't know required/optional could be mixed like this.) How do you get
(defmacro define-action (name (&optional (duration 0)) slot1 slot2 slot3)
  `(install-action ',name ',duration ',slot1 ',slot2 ',slot3))
to macroexpand properly? (ps: How does one record a preferred solution on Stackoverflow for a comment?)

Comment: That should work: `(macroexpand '(define-action foo (3) a b c))` => `(INSTALL-ACTION 'FOO '3 'A 'B 'C)`. Remember that you have to put parens around the duration (or empty parens if you don't have duration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parameter and argument lists: style**

It is useful to have explicit parameter lists. Common Lisp provides extensive support for it. But even then not every parameter list idea can be supported. As jkiiski notes in his comment, it is always helpful to have a speaking parameter list: it helps the developer, the compiler can catch some errors at compile time and Lisp can provide better debugging information.

One of the style rules: optional arguments should be at the end of the argument list. Common Lisp itself violates this at least one place (can only remember one function right now) and it is always painful and error prone.

**Fix the arglist of INSTALL-ACTION**:

```
(defun install-action (name slots &optional (duration 0))
   ...)
```

**Fix the arglist of the macro, too**

Use it like:

```
(define-action move (a b c) 1)
```

A list of things might better be grouped in the macro interface.

```
(defmacro define-action (name slots &optional duration)
   ...)
```

Or even use a keyword named arguments:

```
(define-action move :slots (a b c) :duration 1)
```

It gets longer, but readability is greatly improved.

**Side question: do we need a macro DEFINE-ACTION and why?**

The main reasons for such a macro are usually:

- less quoting
- special syntax
- compile-time side-effects
- expansion into other macro calls

Comment: One word is missing: "optional arguments should be at the <here> of the argument list".

Comment: I was hoping to put the optional parameter second in the lambda list for ease of reading. It is just a number, and the slot arguments are potentially complex trees (see problem edit above). Worried that the optional argument might get too easily overlooked at the end when writing specs. Are slot :keywords the best way then, eventhough they are all required?

Comment: @davypough: the main problem is that optional arguments before required arguments in a flat argument list is not natively supported in Common Lisp. That should give us a hint, that it might not be a good idea.

Comment: @davypough: with keyword arguments you can check if they are actually provided. Then you can also put the duration in front, because the order does not matter.